# Matlab is reading extra characters from arduino serial output

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am having Arduino just output a consistent set of numbers to the COM port. Matlab is reading the COM port and about 1 in 10 times it reads successfully. The other times it adds an extra character or two on the first line. Usually it's a letter with some sort of accent. Below is the code for Matlab and Arduino. What could be adding the extra characters?

**Arduino Code**

```
int output1, output2, output3, area;
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin (9600)
}
void loop() 
{
output1 = 2.0;
output2 = 2.1;
output3 = 3.7;

delay(5);
Serial.print(2.0);
Serial.print(',');
Serial.print(2.1);
Serial.print(',');
Serial.println(3.7);
}
```

**Matlab Code**

```
clear all 
close all
Serialport='com3';
MaxDeviation=3;
TimeInterval=0.2;
loop=120;

s = serial(Serialport);

distance1(1)=0;
time(1)=0;
count = 2;
k=1;
fopen (s);
while ~isequal(count,loop)

%%Serial data accessing 

 distance1 = fgetl(s);
 distance2= textscan(distance1,'%f %f %f','Delimiter', ',');
 distance3(count + 1) = cell2mat(distance2');

 area=(0.5*2.094*((distance3(count,1))^2 + (distance3(count,1))^2 + (distance3(count,1))^2));

count = count + 1;
end

%% Clean up the serial port
fclose(s);
delete(s);
clear s;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nice first question, but generally remove any pleasantries and simply state the question you're hoping to have answered.

Comment: To further isolate your problem, if you print `distance1` do you already see the characters in there?

Comment: I haven't tried printing it, but when I look at the variable, distance1 has the characters there. I will try printing it and see if the characters are there. I do know that they are not there in the arduino output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you usually have to discard the first line, since you don't know when you are turning the serial on.

I mean, you are printing

```
2.0,2.1,3.7\r\n
```

but you can open the port when you have just transmitted the 3, so you will receive

```
.7\r\n
```

So just put an `fgetl` after the `fopen` and you should read correctly.

Just as a note, it's always a good practice to put a starting character in the stream, so you can align at start. Now, since you are sending a new line, you can synchronize on it